# How to get get AuthenticationState in MainLayout and pass it as CascadingValue?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to create an app with two layouts (UnauthorizedLayout - for unauthorized user and MainLayout - for authorized user). I'm having a problem of passing AuthenticationState as CascadingValue.

**App.razor**

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotFoundPage />
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

**MainLayout.razor**

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="main-page">
    <CascadingValue Value="CurrentUser">
        <NavMenu />
        @Body
    </CascadingValue>
</div>


@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }
    public User CurrentUser { get; set; }

    private User GetUser()
    {
        var auth = authenticationStateTask.Result;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(auth.User.FindFirst("user").Value);
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized() => CurrentUser = GetUser();
}
```

However I'm receiving following errors:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime.
   at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Object obj)
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(Object obj, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
   at System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SpinThenBlockingWait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWaitCore(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].get_Result()
   at MytyPro.B2B.Shared.MainLayout.GetUser() in D:\Projects\Test\Shared\MainLayout.razor:line 19
   at MytyPro.B2B.Shared.MainLayout.OnInitialized() in D:\Projects\Test\Shared\MainLayout.razor:line 23
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

and

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MytyPro.B2B.Shared.NavMenu.GetUser() in D:\Projects\Test\Shared\NavMenu.razor:line 86
   at MytyPro.B2B.Shared.NavMenu.OnInitialized() in D:\Projects\Test\Shared\NavMenu.razor:line 81
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

Additional problem is that this is all happening in MainLayout view even I'm still not authorized.

Comment: You can't call .Result like that because it's a blocking call and that's not allowed in a synchronous method. Are you not able to override OnInitializedAsync? (I've not done any Blazor WASM development myself).

Comment: @Lex is correct here, use async version of OnInitialized instead

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.  You're in the async world so you can't intertwine Tasks with sync methods such as `OnInitialized`.

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
      => CurrentUser = await GetUser();

    private async Task<User> GetUser()
    {
        var auth = await authenticationStateTask;
        return auth.User;
    }
```

`authenticationStateTask.Result;` is blocking and may/will lead to deadlocks.

Comment: [Polite] why do you return `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(auth.User.FindFirst("user").Value)`  It should be something like this: var auth = await authenticationStateTask;  return auth.User;

Comment: Thanks, because it was late and I hadn't really examined what that line was doing!  I've updated my answer.

Comment: NP - could you please mark the answer as the solution so others know the question is already answered?